# How to do loop through the values in a row in a datatable in C#?

Tags: c#, loops, datatable

I have a datatable called "`students`" with multiple columns and rows.

I have the column named "`major`" which has the values "Nursing", "Chemistry" "Psychology" and "Graphic Design".

I want to iterate through the values and put the different majors into an array or list.

If there is a ***duplicate*** (for example if there are two students that major in Chemistry) **do not store the value twice**.

How do I implement this?

Comment: What have you tried? What does your code look like now? This is information we need in order to help.

Comment: Pretty much like you said: Iterate through the values. Put them in a list. If there is a duplicate, do not put them in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what is your intent but this little Linq code could help

```
List<string> uniques = dt.AsEnumerable()
                         .Select(x => x["major"].ToString())
                         .Distinct()
                         .ToList();
```

If you want to count the occurences of the various 'majors' then your could write

```
var uniques = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x["major"].ToString())
                .Select(g => new 
                { 
                    major = g.Key, 
                    count=g.Count()
                });
foreach(var u in uniques)
    Console.WriteLine(u.major + "...." + u.count);
```